# How to solve an equation with absolute value and x as exponent.

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, absolute-value

The inequation is: [image]

I thought that the solution would be the same as if there was no x as exponent, but in Microsoft Math it says it has no solution and about the equation it said it has solutions. Look above:

[image]

Can you explain how to solve these inequations?

Comment: $2^x>0 \text{ and } |x-2|\ge 0$ So the only thing that determines  if our fraction is positive (fraction is positive if bottom is positive) or negative (fraction is negative if bottom is negative) is the denominator. Just solve $2x+x^2-3>0$

Comment: $2^x>0$ check!
$|x-2|>0 \iff x\ne 2$ check!
So numerator is always positive (or 0).

$2x+x^2-2>0$... when? Do this last calculation, subtract $\{2\}$ and you will have found the solution set

Comment: @boon heT Yes but this way it has a solution, but in my Microsoft Math says it hasn't.